# Are There Studies Estimating the Prevalence of 'Bullshit Jobs' Across Countries?

Tags: reference-request, labor-economics, empirical-evidence, data

Have there been any studies conducted to estimate the proportion of 'Bullshit Jobs,' as defined by David Graeber, across different countries? Are there any known efforts to visualize this data in a global map, essentially creating a 'BS Jobs' index?

Comment: Does Graeber give an objective definition? It is my understanding that he says a job is bullshit when the person working it will attest that the hypothetical disappearance of the job would have no effect on the functioning of the firm/office/entity it is being performed for, i.e. it is meaningless.

Comment: If true, above means such suverys would rely on self-reporting and employees have a strong incentive not to self-report that their jobs are redundant, thus the data would be very questionable.

Comment: Maybe https://doi.org/10.1177/09500170211015067 and https://doi.org/10.1111/1468-4446.12941 come close to what you are looking for.